# Prevent additional uninstaller uninstall everything

Tags: inno-setup

I have an innosetup installer which installs a plugin into the root directory of an application which is also installed with innosetup. After installing my plugin into this dir there are multiple uninst* files:

```
app/
  unins000.exe (the apps uninstaller)
  unins000.dat
  unins001.exe (another plugin's uninstaller)
  unins001.dat
  unins002.exe (my plugin's uninstaller)
  unins002.dat
```

Problem is running unins002.exe uninstalls **all** files in this folder, I need only the files created by my plugin to be uninstalled.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `[setup]` section you need to provide a different (or non-default) `AppId` value.

When the installer runs and the same the `AppId` exists for an existing uninstall manifest then Inno will merge them.

Comment: In my installer, I set a unique AppId. Just tested again, the AppId string is also found in the uninst002.dat and is different from the ones found in uninst000.dat and uninst001.dat. Still uninst002.exe uninstalls all.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. It was due to a misconfigured UninstallDelete section.